# How to override the Craft forgot password email

Tags: craft-features

Struggling to find any documentation on how to override Craft's HTML for the forgotten password email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation can be found here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/forgot-password-form

Part of the full templating documentation that starts here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/global-variables

The actual HTML side of things is determined by the template you're using, which you can specify in the control panel -> settings -> emails.  I believe these settings are considered 'self documenting' in that there are explanations on that page as to what they do.

One thing worth noting is that IIRC you can't extend a layout template with that template, which is a little unfortunate.  So I have one general layout for all my general emails and duplicate that fully into the system email template.

Comment: That is just the form and not the email that is sent out to users

Comment: I've updated my answer to add where you set the template.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but it was what came up for me in a web search so I wanted to add detail for anyone else who gets here.

In a Craft 3 site I wanted to change the text of the "forgot password" email. Not the HTML, just the text. Some people were getting errors about their links not being valid, so I wanted to add some clarifying text.

What worked for me was creating a translations file at `/translations/en/app.php` — /translations may need to be created, and it should be beside the /config and /vendor folders — of course, if /en is not your language, you'll need to change that.

In app.php I used this text:

```
<?php

return [

'forgot_password_body' => "Hey {{user.friendlyName|e}},\n\nTo reset your {{systemName}} password, click on this link:\n\n<a style=\"color:#e31837;font-weight:bold;\" href=\"{{link}}\">Set New Password</a>\n\n<strong>If you get an “invalid” error</strong>, please try copying and pasting the full link below into a web browser rather than clicking on it. It may be multiple lines!\n\n{{link}}\n\nIf you were not expecting this email, just ignore it.",

];
```

Look to `/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/translations/en/app.php` to see other static translations that can be overridden (substituting "en" with your language, if needed).

Hope that helps someone!